# Rebasing to move over a set of commits from one branch to another. Is my understanding of this process correct?

Tags: git, rebase

I have three branches: `master`, `develop`, and `release`. Off `release`, I branched a separate branch called `my-bug-fix`.

This branch has five commits. I merged this back into `release`, so I basically have this:

[image]

Now I want to take commits `b` through `f` and move those fixes into `develop`. I cannot do a straight merge because I don't want to bring in `c`. So I found out that you can basically do this:

```
git checkout -b my-bug-fix-for-develop h
git rebase --onto develop d^
git checkout develop
git merge my-bug-fix-develop
```

I understand on an abstract level what is happening here. We create a new branch that is pointing to commit `h`. Then we rebase using `develop` as the new base, starting from the parent commit of `d` (so that will include `d` as well`).

What I don't understand, is how this plays out actually, and I'd like to since I don't like to run commands blindly without actually understanding what's going on. Here's my understanding so far. When we create `my-bug-fix-develop`, we end up with this:

[image]

Here's where I'm getting confused. Now when we do `git rebase --onto develop d^`, is git setting the `HEAD` of `my-bug-fix-develop` to point to `b` (i.e., the commit where `develop` starts) first, and *then* replaying all commits from `d` until `h`?

I guess my main question is the significance of `git checkout -b my-bug-fix-for-develop h`. If I branch without specifying `h`, and I tried to do `git rebase --onto develop d^`, I get some other changes that don't even come from the bugfix. Why is it that setting the starting point of the new branch to `h` makes this work?

Here's what I *think* is happening and I'd like to know if I am right or just way off-base. It finds the common ancestor of `my-bug-fix-develop` and `develop`, which is `a`. Then it gets all the diffs from each of the commits on `my-bug-fix-develop`. So that will include `d` through `h` since I specified to start at `d^`. Then it resets the current branch (`my-bug-fix-develop`) to point to `develop` (the branch I am rebasing onto), and then it plays all those commits (`d` through `h`) on top of that.

Is this what is happening?

Comment: I'm a bit confused here by your graphs, because they seem to be a bit inconsistent in the way they are ordered. Do the arrows indicate commit parents? Or commit children?

If they indicate parents, then `my-bug-fix` only contains one commit that isn't in `release`, `d`, and `i`-`e` are not reachable from any branch.

If they indicate children though, then develop has been merged into master and has no parent, and your rebase example would not behave at all like you expect. I'm very confused...

Comment: @Ajedi32 The arrows indicate parents. The branches that I have labeled are simply pointers to individual commits.  I just realized now that I messed up the picture because `my-bug-fix` should also be pointing to `h`. I will change the pictures.

Comment: Okay, thanks. That makes a lot more sense now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`git rebase` would be one way to do this, but I think I would recommend `git cherry-pick` instead:

```
git checkout develop
git cherry-pick c..h
```

The main difference is that `git cherry-pick` won't move your `my-bug-fix` and `my-bug-fix-develop` refs - it will just advance `develop` with the new commits that are copies of the change sets made in commits `d` through `h`.

If you would prefer to have the side branch and merge commit on `develop`, though, so that it looks somewhat like the original branch, then do this instead:

```
git checkout -b develop-bug-fix develop
git cherry-pick c..h
git checkout develop
git merge --no-ff develop-bug-fix
```

Comment: I have definitely used cherry-pick before. I was just curious how the rebasing was working in this case.

Comment: In this case, rebasing pretty much works just like cherry-picking, with the additional step of moving the branch refs when it's done...

Comment: Ah, ok. So it is behaving like rebase normally does? Finding the common ancestor at `a`, and then setting the new branch to point to `b`, and then playing `d` through `h` on top of it?

Comment: @VivinPaliath Well, in this case it's not finding the 'common ancestor' of `develop` and `my-bug-fix-develop`, but of `d^` and `my-bug-fix-develop`. See the docs on this format for rebase: https://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/git-rebase.html (`git rebase --onto <newbase> <upstream>`)